# Full Row Rank And Solution Set

Tags: linear-algebra

For example the following matrix has a full row rank:\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0   \\
  0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
And if a the row rank is full so the linear transformation is onto, but using Rank–nullity theorem $Dim(Im(T))=2$, $DimV=3$ so $Dim(Ker(T))=1$ how can it be onto?

Comment: Well if $T:V \rightarrow W$ then $dim(Im(T))=2=dimW$ hence it is onto. The fact that the kernel has $dim>0$ shows that the transformation is not inyective, but has nothing to do with it being onto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This matrix (by multiplication from left) determines a linear map $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^2$.

It is surjective *onto* $\Bbb R^2$ which is indeed of dimension 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing onto with 1-1. A linear transformation from $V $ to $W $ can be onto and have nontrival kernel as long as $dim(V) $ is greater than $dim (W) $